# In plotly (python API): How to enable latex rendering in offline mode?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, plotly

I am using plotly version 1.9.3, and using it to embed figures in jupyter notebook in offline mode using

```
init_notebook_mode()
```

When I enter TeX notation in labels, titles, etc., the Tex will not render (i.e. $\alpha$ will be displayed as source.

When I use the "save and edit in cloud" toolbar option, in the plotly website it renders correctly.

Can I configure it to render also in the offline mode?

I have both LaTex installation and a local installation of MathJax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the moment, it unfortunately does not seem possible to configure plotly to properly render TeX notations in the offline mode. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/105) on their github repo with several users describing this problem.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, support was added for rendering LaTeX in offline mode in plotly.py version 3.4.0.

From https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#added:

> Added LaTeX typesetting support for figures displayed in the Jupyter Notebook using plotly.offline.iplot and plotly.graph_objs.FigureWidget. Note: There are still outstanding issues with MathJax rendering in FireFox, but it is now working well in Chrome. (#1243)